# Spring MVC Error al correr builder

Tags: spring-mvc

alguien puede ayudarme?,
cuando inicio mi ambiente en Spring MVC, y se carga mi proyecto me sale el síguete error:

```
   Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Marina'.
   Errors occurred during the build.
   Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'Marina'.
   loader constraint violation: loader (instance of 
   org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) previously 
   initiated loading for a different type with name 
   "org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution"
```

Comment: Limpia el proyecto. En netbeans se hace en la opción Clean and Build. Puede que sea solo eso.

Comment: ya lo intente, pero cuando limpio el projecto me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

       Errors occurred during the build.
       Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 
        'modelo'.
         loader constraint violation: loader (instance of 
         org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) 
         previously         
         initiated loading for a different type with name 
         "org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject"